# Create a page with layers on/off

Tags: html, asp.net, css, layer

I am trying to create a page with layers on and off option.

does anyone know how to do this kind of page?

please let me know,
thanks

Comment: This is a set of divs, the one over the other, and a simple javascript that opens and close them, actually change their style by pressing the buttons

Comment: Using jquery would be really helpfull here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/T7HTN/)**</kbd>

```
<button class="on">Show All</button>
<button class="off">Hide All</button>
<button data-rel="one">One</button>
<button data-rel="two">Two</button>
<button data-rel="three">Three</button>

<div class="one layer"></div>
<div class="two layer"></div>
<div class="three layer"></div>
```

---

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
button {
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.one {
  background: url(image1.png) 110px 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.two {
  background: url(image2.png) 250px 150px no-repeat;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
}
.three {
  background: url(image3.png) 410px 310px no-repeat;
  background-size: 80px 80px;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {

  $('button').click(function() {

    var el = $('.'+$(this).data('rel'));

    if(el.css('opacity') === '1') {
       el.stop().animate({ opacity: '0.3' }, 300, 'linear');
    }
    else {
       el.stop().animate({ opacity: '1' }, 300, 'linear');
    }

  });

  $('.on').click(function() {
    $('.layer').stop().animate({ opacity: '1' }, 300, 'linear');    
  });

  $('.off').click(function() {
    $('.layer').stop().animate({ opacity: '0.3' }, 300, 'linear');    
  });

});
```

Comment: thanks for this, i could try with this. but i am not able to get the script to work. I could see the buttons but not calling the functions

Comment: Did you include jQuery library in your `<head>` section? If you're not then add this `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` between `<head> </head>` tags in your document.